# Is `if test x${property} = x;` an assignment or comparison?

Tags: bash

Please make me understand this code.

Is there assignment happening or comparison in bash shell scripting?

```
if test x${property} = x; then
some condition

fi
```

It's never coming inside of this if block

Comment: It's a test/comparison, not an assignment.  In shell, assignments have no spaces around the `=`, amongst other details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here actually you are checking whether the variable is empty or not. If that variable is emplty then if executes that block.

You can see the following explained.

```
> echo ${property}

> if test x${property} = x; then echo variable is empty;fi
variable is empty
> property='some data'
> if test "x${property}" = x; then echo variable is empty;fi
```

You can also check it with -z option.

```
if [ -z "${property}" ]; then 
    echo "variable is empty"
else
    echo "variable is not empty"
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

It's just a way of comparison that's been done in the old shells, which didn't have many options. It tests whether `property` is empty. In modern shells, such as `ksh` or `bash`, you would use `-z` and the equivalent condition would be:

```
if [[ -z ${property} ]]; then
  some condition
fi
```

Comment: No modern shell, and especially not `bash`'s `[[ ... ]]` command, require the `x${var}` hack. `[[ -z $property ]]` is sufficient. In fact, `-z x${var}` will *never* be true, because the argument will always consist of at least the character `x`.